# Form for submitting nested devise user data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :encryptable

  belongs_to :club
end
```

and

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

given that "accepts_nested_attributes_for" must go on the "has_many" side, how do I construct a nested form that accepts nested, devise, user data please?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think it should work:

controller:

> @users = @club.users.build

Form :

```
 form_for @club
  fields_for @users |fr|
    @users.each do |usr|
      text_field :email
      text_field :password
      text_field :pass_conf...
          other fields
    end
   end
   submit
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, however it fails to create a session for the newly created user

Comment: you meant create session later for new users or just after record is created?
In case just after user is created you will have to create user session as devise is not involved
devise_way: sign_in_and_redirect @users.first